# Change table name for admin grid collections

Tags: database, adminhtml, collection, grid

I have created one module for banner. Its working well. In backend, I have an option to add banner image and set active or not.Initially, I have created a table with the name "**banner**" for save banner records.

Now I would like to change the table name like **chilly_banner**. I have created "**chilly_banner**" table manually in DB and inserted some records.

In admin banner grid, I want to show the collections from this table. I don't have any idea, how to do it. But i have tried like this in **_prepareCollection()** method,

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('banner/chilly_banner')->getCollection();
```

And in model file **_init()** method changed banner into **chilly_banner** as like above.

But I got an error like

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function getCollection() on a non-object
 in ../app/code/local/Chilly/Banner/Block/Adminhtml/Banner/Grid.php on
 line 18
```

Have any idea how to change table name in **grid collections** and also want change the table name in **saveAction()** method too?

I'm eagarly awaiting for your response..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Darji, According to magento Model table is not required to same of table

As you told that

```
you table was banner and you have change it to  chilly_banner.
```

So you need to change just table name at config.xml

```
<entities>
    <yourmodule>
        <table>yourtable</table>
    </yourmodule>
</entities>
```

** Just Like: **

```
<entities>
    <banner>
        <table>chilly_banner</table>
    </banner>
</entities>
```

And you can access this table without change model name

```
Mage::getModel('banner/banner')->getCollection()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Its working. Thank you again.

Comment: If this step only enough,and i have been using 2 table in my module, how to tell which table need to take in prepare collection method?

Comment: create a question, i will give u solution

Comment: I have created another thread for my further doubt
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51674/how-to-tell-which-table-should-take-in-prepare-collection-method