# How to tell which table should take in prepare collection method?

Tags: module, magento-1, collection, resource-model

From this [Change table name for admin grid collections](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51662/change-table-name-for-admin-grid-collections/51665#51665) thread, one doubt has come into being.

**If we have been using 2 table in our custom module, how to tell which table should take in prepare collection method?**

Eagarly awaiting for your response!

Comment: are you want to used multiple tables for a model? not module

Comment: for a module...

Comment: on one model or multiple model ,like Mage_Catalog have Mage::getModel('catalog/product')  and  Mage::getModel('catalog/category') ?

Comment: If you explain both type, It will be fine. I don't have any basic idea too in this area..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Multiple Model for a module with One Table for each Model

Creation of Multiple Model for a model is easy.you need to `define multiple entities` to your `Module Model resourceModel` and it `corresponding entity entity_id Table`.

**Example:**

```
        <custommodule_resource>
            <class>Amit_Custommodule_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <custommoduleone>
                    <table>custommoduleTestOne</table>
                </custommoduleone>
        <custommoduletwo>
                    <table>custommoduleTestTwo</table>
        </custommoduletwo>
            </entities>
        </custommodule_resource>
```

**Full model code for Module:**

```
<models>
    <custommodule>
    <class>Amit_Custommodule_Model</class>
    <resourceModel>custommodule_resource</resourceModel>
    </custommodule>
    <custommodule_resource>
    <class>Amit_Custommodule_Model_Resource</class>
    <entities>
        <custommoduleone>
        <table>custommoduleTestOne</table>
        </custommoduleone>
        <custommoduletwo>
        <table>custommoduleTestTwo</table>
        </custommoduletwo>
    </entities>
    </custommodule_resource>
</models>
```

**This model give you two model for a module**

1. `Mage::getModel('custommodule/custommoduletwo')` // as entities is custommoduletwo
2. `Mage::getModel('custommodule/custommoduleone')`

**Process of define class**

According to magento for `each Model` required need to create Corresponding **Model,Resource,Collection** class

**Model class** for model `Mage::getModel('custommodule/custommoduleone')`

```
<?php
class Amit_Custommodule_Model_Custommoduleone extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('custommodule/custommoduleone');
    }

}
```

**Resource class**

app/code/community/Amit/Custommodule/Model/Resource/Custommoduleone.php 
- [See more at](http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/#sthash.uYojP6gU.dpuf):

```
<?php
class Amit_Custommodule_Model_Resource_Custommoduleone extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Initialize resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('custommodule/custommoduleone', 'table_Primarykey');
    }
}
```

**Collection class:**

Collection file path is `Collection.php` app/code/community/Amit/Custommodule/Model/Resource/Custommoduleone

```
<?php
class Amit_Custommodule_Model_Resource_Custommoduleone_Collection
extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract{
    protected function _constuct(){
        $this->_init('custommodule/custommoduleone');    
    }
}
```

**Second model:**

**Model class**

```
<?php
class Amit_Custommodule_Model_CustommoduleTwo extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('custommodule/custommoduletwo');
    }

}
```

**Resource class**

app/code/community/Amit/Custommodule/Model/Resource/Custommoduletwo.php

```
<?php
class Amit_Custommodule_Model_Resource_Custommoduletwo extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Initialize resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('custommodule/custommoduletwo', 'table_Primarykey');
    }
}
```

**Collection class:**

Collection file path is `Collection.php` app/code/community/Amit/Custommodule/Model/Resource/Custommoduletwo

```
<?php
class Amit_Custommodule_Model_Resource_Custommoduletwo_Collection
extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract{
    protected function _constuct(){
        $this->_init('custommodule/custommoduletwo');    
    }
}
```

**NOte:I will provide multiple table for one model shorly**

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I got clear idea about how to use multiple table with multiple model(Each table for each model). Really nice and clear explanation.

Comment: enthusiastically staying here for your answer of multiple table for one model....